# How to add currency at the end of the number with javascript

Tags: javascript

What i am doing here with the javascript below is converting numbers to currency format realtime that works properly.

```
function myFunc(){
    var numb='';
    nStr = document.getElementById('dj_car').value;
    my = nStr.split('.');
    var Len = my.length;
    for (var i=0; i<Len;i++){numb = numb+my[i];}
    x = numb.split('.');
    x1 = x[0];
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;

    while (rgx.test(x1))
    {
       x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + '.' + '$2');
    }
    formated = x1 + x2;
    document.getElementById('dj_car').value = formated;
}
```

My question is how can i put EUR as text at the end of the number? I need to convert number like '1.000 EUR' however as of now it appears like '1.000'

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Please clarify your question. "So i spoiled to add 'EUR' to end of the number to get rid of loop ?" makes no sense.

Comment: Is this about removing the loop or adding the currency?

Comment: i just want to add EUR as a text to end of the number. It should be like "1.000 EUR'

Comment: Can't you just change `formated = x1 + x2;` to `formated = x1 + x2 + ' EUR';`?

Comment: @Egemen if all you need is the display to look like '1.000 EUR' just do `document.getElementById('dj_car').value = formated + ' EUR'`

Comment: than it get in loop that repeats EUR continuously

Comment: That's why i get sticked so it appears like "12 EUR EUR12 EUR EUR EUR"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyone else getting `EUR EUR EUR`? All seems fine to me.

Added `replace()` if you submit it will send EUR into the function so this needs to be removed. I would also recommend more validation.

> **Edit:** I have updated the `.replace()` to strip anything but 0-9.

```js
function myFunc(){
    var numb='';
    //---- Remove EUR if submitted more than once!
    nStr = document.getElementById('dj_car').value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
    my = nStr.split('.');
    var Len = my.length;
    for (var i=0; i<Len;i++){numb = numb+my[i];}
    x = numb.split('.');
    x1 = x[0];
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;

    while (rgx.test(x1))
    {
       x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + '.' + '$2');
    }
    formated = x1 + x2;
    document.getElementById('dj_car').value = formated+'EUR';
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="dj_car" oninput="myFunc()"/>
```

I hope this helps. Happy coding!

Comment: com'on bro , after i have done with adding .replace() it works without repeating EUR. There may be other part of entire code could have involved i am assuming for this strange behavior if you insist to say either way it should work. The code converts number realtime during i am typing not to convert number with pressing button. Thanks anyway

Comment: I will update the answer, you can edit in real time. **Check the snippet for the update** Next time i would recommend displaying your method to fire the function to make it real time so we can work with you rather than have to guess, but the update shows this will work just fine no matter how you call the function. Happy coding!